# How To Select Top Value

Tags: sqlplus

```
SELECT B.CustomerID, SUM(C.UnitPrice * C.Quantity) AS "Total Value"
FROM Orders B, Order_Det C
WHERE B.OrderID = C.OrderID AND “Total Value” = (SELECT MAX(“Total Value”) FROM Order_Det)
GROUP BY B.CustomerID
ORDER BY "Total Value";
```

the following code from the above is what i'd tried.
A customer able to make MULTIPLE orders. thus, i want to display the most valuable customer by sum of multiple their quantity purchases and unit price. 
The problem i faced is i was unable to archive who is the most valuable customer. Please guide me. Tq

Answer (score 0):

here it is!!

```
SELECT O.CustomerID, SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice) AS "Total Value"
FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN Order_Det OD ON O.OrderId = OD.OrderId
GROUP BY O.CustomerID
ORDER BY SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice)
```

or

```
SELECT O.CustomerID, SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice) AS "Total Value"
FROM Orders O, Order_Det OD 
WHERE O.OrderId = OD.OrderId
GROUP BY O.CustomerID
ORDER BY SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice)
```

and for most valuable customer,

```
SELECT TOP 1 O.CustomerID
FROM Orders O 
INNER JOIN Order_Det OD ON O.OrderId = OD.OrderId
GROUP BY O.CustomerID
ORDER BY SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice) DESC
```

Comment: Ya is something like that but i just want display only one customer, who is having highest purchased value. That's why called as "MOST VALUABLE CUSTOMER" :)

Comment: There's a ERROR at line 1: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

Comment: don't know why. it's working for me on ms-sql server 2005. which DB server you are using? what's your final query-complete query-code?

Comment: Oracle11g i am using. How to see? @@ P/S: new to oracle.

Comment: not sure how its in oracle, but query can be: SELECT * from (SELECT * O.CustomerID FROM Orders O INNER JOIN Order_Det OD ON O.OrderId = OD.OrderId GROUP BY O.CustomerID ORDER BY SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice) DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1...........
see [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)

Comment: now i change my statement to this is should be work fine if i remove the SELECT O.CUSTOMERID. but if i SELECT O.CUSTOMERID is occur ORA-00937: NOT A SINGLE-GROUP FUNCTION. how to fix that?
SELECT O.CUSTOMERID, MAX(SUM(OD.UNITPRICE * OD.QUANTITY)) AS "TOTAL"
FROM ORDERS O, ORDER_DET OD
WHERE O.CUSTOMERID = OD.CUSTOMERID
GROUP BY O.CUSTOMERID

Comment: the error u'r facing is due to MAX function in select query..do this things instead of MAX.. (1)do order by descending on SUM(OD.UNITPRICE * OD.QUANTITY) (2)select top 1 value.. the query i provided was for mssql server, same query you can build for oracle from the [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) i provided.one point: "WHERE rownum = 1" will select first record from the result-for oracal.